# Escape codes not working inside PowerShell form

Tags: forms, powershell, escaping

I need some help, please.

If you run this PowerShell code, you will see two lines displayed in different colours.

```
Clear-Host
$ESC = [char]27

"$ESC[38;2;102;255;255m$('Can you see this?')$ESC[0m"

Function DisplayEscapeCodes
{
    "$ESC[38;2;153;51;255m$('What about this?')$ESC[0m"
}

DisplayEscapeCodes
```

I'm having a problem when trying to display coloured text using escape codes inside a PowerShell form. If you run the code below, the only text that will be displayed is "Can you see this?"

```
Clear-Host
$ESC = [char]27

"$ESC[38;2;102;255;255m$('Can you see this?')$ESC[0m"

Function EndForm
{
    "$ESC[38;2;2;102;78m$('Or this?')$ESC[0m"
    $OKButton.Dispose();
    $Form.Dispose();
    $Form.Close()
}

Function DisplayEscapeCodes
{
    EndForm
    "$ESC[38;2;153;51;255m$('What about this?')$ESC[0m"
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Test"
$Form.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Segoe UI Light',14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,400) 
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.ControlBox = $False
$Form.ShowIcon = $False
$Form.BackColor = "White"
$Form.ForeColor = "Black"
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "Fixed3D"
$Form.ShowInTaskbar = $False
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.Topmost = $True

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,200)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,40)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({Write-Host (DisplayEscapeCodes)})

$Form.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? I need to use escape codes because they provide far more than the standard 16 PowerShell colours.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Thanks to Martin, I was able to get the "What about this?" text to appear by making the change he suggested. As I also mentioned, I'd simplified the code to make it easy to follow. If I change the DisplayEscapeCodes function to as shown below, it doesn't quite work as I'd hoped.

```
Function DisplayEscapeCodes
{
    EndForm
    "$ESC[38;2;153;51;255m$('What about this?')$ESC[0m"
    "$ESC[38;2;204;0;204m$('And this?')$ESC[0m"
}
```

Both text blocks appear, but on the same line and in the same colour. Any ideas?

Comment: The [coloring] escape codes only work to text written to the Console (as the Console interprets them). They will no work in an arbitrary [winforms] control. Also, the result of those string expressions are *going nowhere* .. that has nothing to do with the escape codes and it might as well be "Hello world!". Using an explicit Write-Host would sort that bit out.

Comment: `{DisplayEscapeCodes}` -> `{Write-Host (DisplayEscapeCodes)}`

Comment: Martin, that worked, thanks. I simplified my script somewhat to make sure it was easy to follow, but I'll see if I can adapt your solution.

Comment: user2864740, the output is intended to appear on the console, not within the form. As I explained, I need to use escape codes because they offer a far wider range of colours than the 16 usually available. If Write-Host can be adapted to use RGB or HTML codes, I'm all ears!

Comment: 24 bit color depth? `https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Communary.ConsoleExtensions/1.0.69/Content/Functions%5CWrite-RGB.ps1`